# Unity Highscore reset at respawn

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to be able to respawn as well as reset the score counting as soon as i walk into my "Gold" Object.
As for now i'm not even able to respawn which was possible earlier before trying to implement the "Score-Stuff" (at first the "FoundGold" Script was only used to be able to respawn). Also i'm trying to make the lowest Score the High-Score.
Note that im new to C# and i kinda put everything together from the tutorials i needed so a answer with some actual code/stating where something went wrong would be much appreciated.

```
//GoldFound Code
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;



public class GoldFound : MonoBehaviour
{
private ScoreManager theScoreManager;
public Transform target;

[SerializeField] private Transform player;
[SerializeField] private Transform respawnpoint;

private void Start()
{
    theScoreManager = FindObjectOfType<ScoreManager>();
}


private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    theScoreManager.scoreIncreasing = false;
    player.transform.position = respawnpoint.transform.position;
    theScoreManager.scoreCount = 0;
    theScoreManager.scoreIncreasing = true;

}


}
```

other code

```
//ScoreManager
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;


public class ScoreManager : MonoBehaviour
{

public Text scoreText;
public Text hiScoreText;

public float scoreCount;
public float hiScoreCount;

public float pointPerSecond;

public bool scoreIncreasing; 


// Use this for initialization
void Start()
{

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    if (scoreIncreasing)
    {
        scoreCount += pointPerSecond * Time.deltaTime;
    }

    if(scoreCount > hiScoreCount)
    {
        hiScoreCount = scoreCount;
    }


    scoreText.text = "Score: " + Mathf.Round (scoreCount);
    hiScoreText.text = "High Score: " + Mathf.Round (hiScoreCount);

}
}
```

Comment: I feel like the first thing you should do is separate your tasks. Make methods for score reset, some for player position reset etc... then make behaviors who use them appropriately, trying to do everything hardcoded makes for a big bowl of spaghetti code. By splitting them up, you first guarantee they work, then you use them how you want, without having to modify your initial code.

Comment: Also, changing the text at each update to the same value is really redundant, you're probably modifying UI elements, to which I ask, where is `OnGUI()` ? Secondly, you should refresh the score only if it changes, not every frame.

Comment: Thirdly, I don't get why you are setting `theScoreManager.scoreIncreasing` to `true` and `false` in a single call, seeing that it is never used in between, it's basically always `true` which makes me fail to understand it's purpose.

Comment: If you want the lowest score to be your best, just inverse the condition of your if statement : `if(scoreCount < hiScoreCount)
    {
        hiScoreCount = scoreCount;
    }`

Comment: Okay so, it'd be great if you were able to give some feedback, but i'm going to try and understand what you want to do, you seem to want to make a sort of running game of sort, where the faster you go, the lower your score is, and the better it is. Maybe it's finishing a maze or something. How you are doing it with your `bool theScoreManager.scoreIncreasing` is kind of useless from what I see. It is absolutely always true, at least after touching GoldFound stuff. I also don't really see the need for it's system also. you could do the same without.

Comment: Another thing you should be careful about, is that you'd be locked in your TriggerEnter, when you reset the score, which might/could have changed with the logic you want, but you don't check it, so people might lose a bit of score etc... Also, since you seem to be time based, it would be good to make a CoRoutine for your score counter instead of being on unity's main thread, which is less reliant for time based events since you are dependent on your processing speed, which means the time between your score updates won't always be the same. And for your players too, depending on their hardware.

Comment: @Antry Hi, thanks for taking the time. Yes the game is supposed to be a maze. The thing is i have absolutely no idea of C# because its for a specific subject in school we only have 3x8 hours.. I wrote my scripts through watching tutorials according to what i was looking for, which worked fine until i wanted two ideas together which is why the code isn't really structured. What i was trying to do with the "scoreIncreasing" is: stopping it right before death because its running by default, then right after respawning starting it again. I'll try to take your input into consideration, thanks.

Comment: Cool, alright ! Remember that your code is ran line by line, you need to think like that. Detail each step. Try and make simple systems, instead of trying to do everything by hand at every corner you need, that's the best way you'll get things to work and to have a scale-able project.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to save your highscore in-between play sessions, then the easiest way to do so is to save the value to PlayerPrefs. If you want to start saving more / more complex stuff you really should save it in a file you generate yourself. But in your case, PlayerPrefs is fine.

Here's a Unity tutorial on the subject:
https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/high-score-playerprefs

Otherwise, you can just do it like this:

```
public void SetHighscore (float currentScore)
{
    if (PlayerPrefs.HasKey("highscore"))
    {
        float highscore = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("highscore");
        if (highscore > currentScore)
        {
            PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("highscore", currentScore);
            PlayerPrefs.Save();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("highscore", currentScore);
        PlayerPrefs.Save();
    }
}
```

Then just write PlayerPrefs.GetKey("highscore") whenever you need it.
(Though I'd also recommend you check if it exists by using the PlayerPrefs.HasKey("highscore"))
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html

Comment: Oh, and where you're writing player.transform.position and respawnPoint.target.position, you can ditch the extra "transform" in between. You're already referring to the Transform component, so you can just write player.position.

Other than that your code looks like it should work fine. (Except for the points made in the comments)

Comment: @Jebr If this comment has answered your question, please accept it. If not, please give some more information on what still doesn't work.